# Получение и суммирование Timedelta

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timedelta

Дано: список пар числовых значений, в котором значение `[0]` означает индекс в таблице, с которого начинается некий процесс, а индекс `[1]`- индекс конца процесса. Этим индексам, конечно, соответствует запись в столбце `['Время']`

Задача: 1) получить `timedelta`-объект равный времени между `Timestamp` индекса`[1]` и `[0]`
2) Получить сумму таких `timedelta` - то есть выяснить суммарное время некоего процесса.

Желаемый результат примерно описан в документации:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dti = pd.to_datetime(['1/1/2018', 
                     np.datetime64('2018-01-01'),datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1)])
dti = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=10, freq='4H')
dti = dti.tz_localize('UTC')
t1 = dti[3:5]-dti[1:3]
t2 = t1
print(type(t1))
sum(t1,datetime.timedelta())

>>> <class 'pandas.core.indexes.timedeltas.TimedeltaIndex'>
Timedelta('0 days 16:00:00')
```

Очевидно, что в таком формате не представляет проблемы выполнить поэлементное вычитание срезов одинакового размера.

Теперь применяю подход к реальной задаче, но не выходит.

Код:

```
def all_pattern_times(data, conditions, eps):
    # total_time - принимает значение, равное разности 
    # времени последнего и первого замера

    total_time = data['Время'].iloc[-1]-data['Время'].iloc[0]
    print(total_time, type(total_time))

    # обход идет по количеству интересующих процессов:....
    for condition1, condition2 in list(zip(conditions['conditions1'], conditions['conditions2'])):
        # Список с парами индексов, обозначающих начало и конец проявления конкретного процесса, он приходит из другой функции
        times = np.array(pattern_time(data, condition1, condition2, eps))
        try:
             print(data['Время'].iloc[times[3:5, 1]]-data['Время'].iloc[times[3:5, 0]] , type(data['Время'].iloc[times[3, 0]]))
           # print(sum(data['Время'][times[:, 1]] - data['Время'][times[:, 0]],datetime.timedelta()))
            out.append(round(sum(data['Время'].iloc[times[:, 1]] - data['Время'].iloc[times[:, 0]],datetime.timedelta()) / total_time * 100, 2))
        except IndexError:
            out.append(0)
    return out
```

И вот какой результат:

```
202 days 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta'>
6151   NaT
6172   NaT
6554   NaT
6568   NaT
Name: Время, dtype: timedelta64[ns] <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
7500   NaT
7525   NaT
8173   NaT
8178   NaT
Name: Время, dtype: timedelta64[ns] <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
1737   NaT
2572   NaT
2874   NaT
2969   NaT
Name: Время, dtype: timedelta64[ns] <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
12562   NaT
12574   NaT
12857   NaT
13110   NaT
Name: Время, dtype: timedelta64[ns] <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

Я капитально зарылся в типах переменных, С единичными индексами типа `data['Время'].iloc[times[4, 1]] - data['Время'].iloc[times[4, 0]]` все работает, а со срезами уже нет.

В результате хочу поделить сумму временных отрезков, когда проявлялся процесс, на общее время работы оборудования. Но не могу сумму этих временных отрезков

```
Пример данных (data):
            x1            x2                  x3                   Время  \
0          0.0           0.0                 65.51 2018-12-01 00:00:00.000   
1          1.0           1.0                 65.49 2018-12-01 00:15:00.000   
2          2.0           2.0                   NaN 2018-12-01 00:25:33.000   
3          3.0           3.0                 65.44 2018-12-01 00:29:59.997   
4          4.0           4.0                 65.37 2018-12-01 00:45:00.000   
5          5.0           5.0                   NaN 2018-12-01 00:48:04.997   
6          6.0           6.0                 65.35 2018-12-01 01:00:00.000   
7          7.0           7.0                   NaN 2018-12-01 01:06:06.000   
8          8.0           8.0                 65.29 2018-12-01 01:14:59.997   
9          9.0           9.0                 65.20 2018-12-01 01:30:00.000   
10        10.0          10.0                   NaN 2018-12-01 01:34:58.000   
11        11.0          11.0                 65.14 2018-12-01 01:45:00.000   
12        12.0          12.0                   NaN 2018-12-01 01:55:21.997   
13        13.0          13.0                 65.09 2018-12-01 01:59:59.997   
14        14.0          14.0                 65.05 2018-12-01 02:15:00.000   
15        15.0          15.0                   NaN 2018-12-01 02:16:22.000   
16        16.0          16.0                 65.01 2018-12-01 02:30:00.000   
17        17.0          17.0                   NaN 2018-12-01 02:36:18.000   
18        18.0          18.0                 64.97 2018-12-01 02:44:59.997   
19        19.0          19.0                   NaN 2018-12-01 02:55:12.000   

                          x4                  x5                 x6  \
0                      28.36                 NaN              28.14   
1                      28.26                 NaN              28.16   
2                        NaN                 NaN                NaN   
3                      28.27                 NaN              28.16   
4                      28.34                 NaN              28.13   
5                        NaN                 NaN                NaN   
6                      28.46                 NaN              28.12   
7                        NaN                 NaN                NaN   
8                      28.81                 NaN              28.51   
9                      28.69                 NaN              28.55   
10                       NaN                 NaN                NaN   
11                     28.55                 NaN              28.51   
12                       NaN                 NaN                NaN   
13                     28.55                 NaN              28.48   
14                     28.76                 NaN              28.55   
15                       NaN                 NaN                NaN   
16                     28.64                 NaN              28.56   
17                       NaN                 NaN                NaN   
18                     28.75                 NaN              28.56   
19                       NaN                 NaN                NaN   

                       x7        x8              x9           x10   x11  \
0               27.052355      ост.             NaN           NaN   NaN   
1               26.938015       NaN             NaN           NaN   NaN   
2               26.910000       NaN             NaN           NaN   NaN   
3               26.945633       NaN             NaN           NaN   NaN   
4               26.983747       NaN             NaN           NaN   NaN   
5               27.050000       NaN             NaN           NaN   NaN   
6               27.117147       NaN             NaN           NaN   NaN   
7               27.260000       NaN             NaN           NaN   NaN   
8               27.433487       NaN             NaN           NaN   NaN   
9               27.292465       NaN             NaN           NaN   NaN   
10              27.390000       NaN             NaN           NaN   NaN   
11              27.235298       NaN             NaN           NaN   NaN   
12              27.080000       NaN             NaN           NaN   NaN   
13              27.231483       NaN             NaN           NaN   NaN   
14              27.448730       NaN             NaN           NaN   NaN   
15              27.470000       NaN             NaN           NaN   NaN   
16              27.334389       NaN             NaN           NaN   NaN   
17              27.300000       NaN             NaN           NaN   NaN   
18              27.406807       NaN             NaN           NaN   NaN   
19              27.300000       NaN             NaN           NaN   NaN   

           x12    x13      x14  
0          NaN    0          0  
1          NaN    0          0  
2          NaN    0          0  
3          NaN    0          0  
4          NaN    0          0  
5          NaN    0          0  
6          NaN    0          0  
7          NaN    0          0  
8          NaN    0          0  
9          NaN    0          0  
10         NaN    0          0  
11         NaN    0          0  
12         NaN    0          0  
13         NaN    0          0  
14         NaN    0          0  
15         NaN    0          0  
16         NaN    0          0  
17         NaN    0          0  
18         NaN    0          0  
19         NaN    0          0  

Список пар индексов начала и конца (times):

[[ 1  3]
 [ 5  6]
 [9  10]
 [15 17]
 [18 19]]
```

Comment: можете привести в вопросе небольшой вопроизводимый пример данных (DataFrame)?

Comment: Прошу прощения за немного неудобный формат

Comment: можете также привести желаемый результат?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если я правильно понял задачу:

```
In [65]: df
Out[65]:
      x1    x2     x3                   Время
0    0.0   0.0  65.51 2018-12-01 00:00:00.000
1    1.0   1.0  65.49 2018-12-01 00:15:00.000
2    2.0   2.0    NaN 2018-12-01 00:25:33.000
3    3.0   3.0  65.44 2018-12-01 00:29:59.997
4    4.0   4.0  65.37 2018-12-01 00:45:00.000
..   ...   ...    ...                     ...
15  15.0  15.0    NaN 2018-12-01 02:16:22.000
16  16.0  16.0  65.01 2018-12-01 02:30:00.000
17  17.0  17.0    NaN 2018-12-01 02:36:18.000
18  18.0  18.0  64.97 2018-12-01 02:44:59.997
19  19.0  19.0    NaN 2018-12-01 02:55:12.000

[20 rows x 4 columns]

In [66]: intervals = np.array(
    ...: [[ 1,  3],
    ...:  [ 5,  6],
    ...:  [9,  10],
    ...:  [15, 17],
    ...:  [18, 19]])
```

---

```
In [67]: res = pd.Series([df.loc[a:b, "Время"].max() - df.loc[a:b, "Время"].min() for a,b in intervals]).sum()
```

---

результат:

```
In [68]: res
Out[68]: Timedelta('0 days 01:02:01.003000')
```

Comment: спасибо! То что нужно, скажите только, в чем смысл методов max() и min()?
Я правильно понимаю, что таким бинарным способом мы определяем конец процесса (он по времени позже, отсюда max) и начало процесса в списке из всего двух времен?

Comment: @StepanSokol, некоторые интервалы содержат три записи - соответственно нужен способ посчитать разницу времени для трёх событий. Но опять же, я не уверен что вам нужен именно такой способ

Comment: Было бы неплохо если бы вы объяснили как считать время в интервалах, состоящих из более чем двух строк

Comment: Откуда берутся интервалы, я сказать не могу, мне их дают, если начну копать эту функцию, попробую это по фиксить. По логике вещей их должно быть два, Начало-Конец, фиксируемые на датчиках. Хорошая защита от плохих данных - в форме min-max